# GIT: post-receive -> get pushed branchname

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I would like to get the name of a branch which is being pushed to my remote.
For example:
When I push the local branch `feature/awesome` to `f5/master` (`f5` is a test server of me), I would like to get the `feature/awesome` string in my post-receive hook.

I already accomplished with the help of SO to get the name of the branch where the push was received:

```
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    echo "$oldrev" > last.txt # a hash
    echo "$newrev" >> last.txt # a hash
    echo "$refname" >> last.txt # refs/heads/master
    echo "$branch" >> last.txt # master
done
```

My target is to send the information to a service which is writing it to a database and then create an overview about which features is currently pushed to which test server.

But I am struggling with getting the pushed feature name. Does anyone know if this is possible and how I could achieve this?

Another solution would be to push the local branch to the test server directly instead of pushing it to the master branch. I would like to avoid this to have only one branch on my server.

Answer (score 1):

Local refs are not always necessary in a push. If `feature/awesome` points at commit `abc123`,  `git push origin feature/awesome:master` and `git push origin abc123:master` are the same.

If you have strict naming rules for local branches and regular workflows for pushes, you can try [-o/--push-option](http://%20https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---push-optionltoptiongt) ,`git push origin --push-option=feature/awesome feature/awesome:master`. In [post-receive](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive), you can get the string `feature/awesome` from the env variable `GIT_PUSH_OPTION_0`. You need to check if your version of Git supports this feature.